# how to convert a data file of type .py imported in a float array?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I'm doing a mathematical GUI with python. The GUI imports any .py file. The .py are arrays.

My question is: How do I make the .py file imported by FileOpen action becomes a ndarray to draw, etc?

This is the code:

```
import sys 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io

from guiTIEMPOFFT import*

class MiFormulario(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.actionOpen_File, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.openfile)


        def openfile(self):

        scan = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open Data File", "", ".py data files (*.py)" )



if __name__=="__main__":
    app= QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp= MiFormulario()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

If security is of no concern for you, you can directly import the .py files as modules. For example if `data.py` would contain:

```
a = [1., 2., 3.]
```

Using __import__:

```
d = __import__("data")
print(d.a)
a = [1., 2., 3.]
```

This would require that you do not open the file via the QFileDialog but just take the name and strip the .py at the end.

Comment: Your answer is pretty good but i need to open the .py via QFileDialog. Thank you

Comment: getOpenFileName seems to return a QString. I guess this should be the filename. If you then remove the `.py` from the filename you can use `__import__`. Otherwise if you have read the content from the file as a string you could use `exec` on the string.